# Convert six column flex layout into three columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a row with six list items. On breakpoint `992px`, I'm looking to turn this six column layout into a three column layout.

I can simply do `flex-direction: column` for a single column, but unsure on how I would go about it for a three column layout.

Current approach:

```css
.list-items-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.list_item-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .list-items-ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-items-ul">
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 1</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 2</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 3</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 4</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 5</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 6</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't wana use `column` at all. Just tell  the `ul` to `wrap` with `flex-wrap:wrap;` and make the width of the `li` tag take up the percentage of the available columns you want. For example if you want 3 columns you use `33.33%` width on the `li` if you want 2 columns you use `50%`.

Additionally you have to remove the border from the `li` tag and put it on the inner div so it doesn't mess with the 33.33% width value.

**A:** Remove the css for the li tag.

**B:** Add this:

```
.list_item-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .list-items-ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .list-items-ul li { width: 33.33%;}
}
```

### **Full example:**

```css
.list-items-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.list_item-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .list-items-ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .list-items-ul li { width: 33.33%;}
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-items-ul">
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 1</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 2</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 3</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 4</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 5</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 6</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex-direction: row;` to ul and [`flex:0 1 45%;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) to li in `media-query`

```css
.list-items-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.list_item-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .list-items-ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  li{
   flex:0 1 45%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-items-ul">
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 1</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 2</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 3</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 4</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 5</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list_item-container">
      <span>Col 6</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution for you if you want to keep flex-direction: column.

```
 .list-items-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.list_item-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .list-items-ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  li{
    width: calc(100%/3);
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Jquery: select and get height from the List Item, this example I just assume it is the same, but in the real project, each list item will be different id. Basically, the ideas is wrap the outerHeight from Col 1 and Col 2 and then sum it and set that height to the parent, so the flex-wrap: wrap will work. Every time it meets that height, it will move to the next row. And it will auto adjust when content changing.

```
const container = $('.list-items-ul');
const heightListItem = $('li').outerHeight(); //have to grap the height from each item and sum it
const heightContainer = container.outerHeight(heightListItem*2);
```